# No submit request sent out by GWT file upload

Tags: gwt, file-upload

GWT 2.5.0 `DevMode`

I had a simple test on `file upload` below,

startupUrl: `http://127.0.0.1:8888/UploadTest.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`

```xml
<g:FormPanel ui:field="fpUpload">
    <g:VerticalPanel>
        <g:FileUpload name="fileData" ui:field="fuUpload" />
        <g:Button ui:field="btUpload">Upload</g:Button>
    </g:VerticalPanel>
</g:FormPanel>
```

```java
@UiHandler("btUpload")
public void onClickUploadButton(ClickEvent e) {
    System.out.println("fileName:" + fuUpload.getFilename());
    fpUpload.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    fpUpload.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
    fpUpload.setAction("/files");
    fpUpload.submit();
    System.out.println("Submitted, please wait!");
}

@UiHandler("fpUpload")
public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Submit completed!");
}
```

Output:

```
fileName:C:\fakepath\one_file_chosen_to_upload
Submitted, please wait!
```

However, the server didn't receive the `submit request`, so "Submit completed!" never appeared.

Meanwhile, the traffic was snooped below, the `submit request` didn't send out at all.

```
$ tcpdump -A -i lo port 8888
```

No exceptions were thrown, too. Any idea?

**@EDIT**

The problem is reproducible on `ProdMode`.

**@EDIT 2**

After merely rebooting the machine, now the problem seems gone just as silently as the `http submit request` was ignored to emit over the wire. Unfortunately, i have no clues why.

Comment: Anything in the devmode log? Does the `/files` context/servlet exist? Try a breakpoint in that?

Comment: Yes, i did step into `FormPanel#submit` but hardly found anything beneficial. What could stop the client from sending the `http submit request` itself, having `FormPanel#submit` been called and when the network connection (tcp socket) between c/s persists.

Comment: And, `/files` context/servlet lives to await the `submit request`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not coded an appropriate servlet to handle the multipart request, also you have to configure that servlet in your `web.xml`. Could you add to your question your servlet code and the content of your `web.xml` ?

Note that `onSubmitComplete` is not executed if the server return a 404. Try to inspect the server response with Firebug, or change the form action by any thing so as you get the same failure.

FYI, there is a ibrary: [gwtupload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted) which is very easy to use and is plenty of nice features, maybe you could take a look to theirs [example](http://gwtupload.alcala.org/) page and give a try.